# Excel vba - index - match - array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, indexing

I want to implement in excel VBA the following Excel formula.

The formula is in array {}

```
{=INDEX($B$3:$B$25,MATCH($A$32 & $B$32,$A$3:$A$25 & $M$3:$M$25,0))}

$B$3:$B$25 - the range from where I want the value ; 

$A$32 - criteria 1 ;
$B$32 - criteria 2

$A$3:$A$25 - criteria range 1 ;
$M$3:$M$25 - criteria range 2
```

Thank you for your support,
Daniel

Comment: You have permission to do so.  But what is your question?

Comment: My question is: What is the VBA code to implement that formula?

Comment: @ChDaniel: This site is not for demanding code from other users. It is about helping each other with problems. You should first try some things for yourself and then ask for help. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Turn on the macro recorder, then enter your formula.  Then, review the code. It'll have the way to use the formula in the recorded code.  Take that and apply as needed.

Comment: Actually I'm the noob in this. I'm not ashamed to say this.

Comment: @RGA What is wrong with people like you here. Not everyone is an expert, give the guy a break.

Comment: @KyloRen I apologize that I can't always withold my frustration, but I spend everyday answering questions in the various VBA tags which are constantly overrun with questions like this.  I get tired of constantly explaining that this is not a free code service, and occasionally can't contain the frustration.  I have, however, removed the comment, as I can now admit it was a bit more than necessary

Comment: And whoever gave the pity upvote is only contributing to the problem

Comment: @RGA, I gave the pity upvote. Ignoring the question if you don't like it is a good solution IMO.

Comment: @RGA - It's OK. Believe me. It's not like I had this issue and I've posted it online and that's it. I've spent over 4 hours in trying to find the solution of it. But with no result. After that I've posted online. Your are true that the way I've posted was not the proper one. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @ChDaniel As illustrated in the help section on how to ask, if you've conducted research **Absolutely tell us that you have**. Even if you have no coding knowledge, people will be much more inclined to help you (or at the very least they won't downvote your question into oblivion).  Even appending your research now can help reverse some of those downvotes

Comment: @RGA, I am just a little sensitive to "noob" treatment, no offence. Cheers, Dave

Comment: And actually, @KyloRen, just about [all of SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308366/6408573) would disagree with you on that point

Comment: @KyloRen I wasn't intending to call OP a "noob," was just trying to add a touch of humor to my comment (admittedly poorly executed, hence why i removed it)

Comment: @RGA, I don't like the rest of SO. The newer members who have knowledge seem much more helpful.

Comment: @RGA, I appreciate your frustration. But, my policy is to ignore posts I don't agree with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the formula in the desired range. You will need to adjust any ranges to suit what you need.

```
Cells(3, 2).Resize(23).FormulaArray = _
        "=INDEX(R3C2:R25C2,MATCH(R32C1 & R32C2,R3C1:R25C1 & R3C13:R25C13,0))"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working fine. I understand now the mechanism. I will adapt this one to an user form.

Comment: If it helps then please upvote and mark the answer as solved.

Comment: Because I'm under 15 reputation the upvote is recorded but it is not displayed. Thank you KyloRen for the support.

Comment: @ChDaniel, no worries, keep plugging along. Yo will get there eventuially